# Convert arules Transaction Data to an item matrix in R programming

Tags: r, apriori, arules, binary-matrix

I have a dataset with 100,000 rows in a transaction format as below

```
B038-82C81778E81C   Toy Story
B038-82C81778E81C   Planet of the apes
B038-82C81778E81C   Iron Man
9C05-EE9B44E8C18F   Bruce Almighty
9C05-EE9B44E8C18F   Iron Man
9C05-EE9B44E8C18F   Toy Story
8F59-9956070D8005   Toy Story
8F59-9956070D8005   Gravity
8F59-9956070D8005   Iron Man
8F59-9956070D8005   Gone
B52F-9936734525AF   Planet of the Apes
B52F-9936734525AF   Bruce Almighty
```

I want to convert it in a matrix format as below (or TRUE/ FALSE Flag)

```
Matrix              Toy Story  Planet of the Apes  Iron Man  Bruce Almighty   Gone  Gravity
B038-82C81778E81C    1             1                 1             0            0     0
9C05-EE9B44E8C18F    1             0                 1             1            0     0 
8F59-9956070D8005    1             0                 1             0            1     1
B52F-9936734525AF    0             1                 0             1            0     0
```

I have tried the following steps

```
TrnsDataset1<-read.transactions("~/Desktop/movieswid_1Copy.txt", format= c("single"), sep="\t", cols = c(1,2), rm.duplicates=TRUE);
L <- as(TrnsDataset1,"list");
M <- as(L,"matrix")
CM<- as (M,"ngCMatrix");
```

But, in my List conversion I am getting the output as

```
B038-82C81778E81C   c("Toy Story\nB038-82C81778E81C\tPlanet of the apes\nB038-82C81778E81C\tIron Man")
9C05-EE9B44E8C18F   c("Bruce Almighty","Iron Man","Toy Story")
```

So some rows are perfect but in some the Unique id is being added in the movie list with \t and \n

I want the list in the below format
   9C05-EE9B44E8C18F   c("Bruce Almighty","Iron Man","Toy Story")

this way I believe I will be easily achieve the required result. Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused because you say you want two things. If you just want the sparse matrix, then you can skip the list and standard matrix transformation. you can just do

```
TrnsDataset1 <- read.transactions(...);
mm <- t(as(TrnsDataset1,"ngCMatrix"))
```

This results in

```
4 x 6 sparse Matrix of class "ngCMatrix"
                  Bruce Almighty Gone Gravity Iron Man Planet Toy Story
8F59-9956070D8005              .    |       |        |      .         |
9C05-EE9B44E8C18F              |    .       .        |      .         |
B038-82C81778E81C              .    .       .        |      |         |
B52F-9936734525AF              |    .       .        .      |         .
```

which is a matrix of true/false values (here abbreviate to fit in space). There is no need to go through the list form at all.